# Interpretation of solutions in simplex

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

Suppose we have problem of maximizing some cost function $c'x$ subjecto to $Ax = b$ and $x \geq 0$. The optimal solution is given by a basis $B$ (subset of $A$'s columns) such that
$$\mathbf{x}_B = B^{-1}b$$

I understand the theory behind the simplex algorithm, but I still cannot see why a variable is appearing in the $i$-th constraint after solving. In particular, why
$$ (\mathbf{x}_B)_i = (B^{-1}b)_i$$
and not any other variable. Does this have any interpretation? (For instance, in max flow)

Comment: If $\mathbf x_B = B^{-1}b$, then of course $(\mathbf x_B)_i = (B^{-1}b)_i$; you're just taking the $i$-th component of both sides.